# How to control the amount of places after the decimal point?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

I tried @"%.3g" but it's not working correctly, when I use it the first formula rounds off to one decimal place, the 2nd & 3rd formulas look ok, the 5th one & the 7th one come out weird (1.52e+03) & (9.23e+03). below are my formula's.
I would like to do each one separately as some need to be rounded off to two places and some to three places.
Thanks so much.

```
double VolumePerMtrCubicMtr = ((3.141592654/4 * ([textField1.text doubleValue]/1000) * ([textField1.text doubleValue]/1000)) - (3.141592654/4 * ([textField2.text doubleValue]/1000) * ([textField2.text doubleValue]/1000))) * [textField5.text doubleValue];
volumePerMeterCubicMeterAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumePerMtrCubicMtr];

double VolumePerMtrLitres = [volumePerMeterCubicMeterAnswer.text doubleValue] * 1000;
volumePerMeterLitreAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumePerMtrLitres];

double LubricationPumpCapacity = [textField6.text doubleValue] / 1000 * [volumePerMeterLitreAnswer.text doubleValue];
pumpSpeedAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", LubricationPumpCapacity];

double VolumePerPipeCubicMtr = [volumePerMeterCubicMeterAnswer.text doubleValue] *[textField3.text doubleValue];
volumePerPipeCubicMeterAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumePerPipeCubicMtr];

double VolumePerPipeLitre = [volumePerMeterLitreAnswer.text doubleValue] * [textField3.text doubleValue];
volumePerPipeLitreAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumePerPipeLitre];

double VolumeForDriveCubicMtr = [volumePerMeterCubicMeterAnswer.text doubleValue] * [textField4.text doubleValue];
volumeForDriveCubicMeterAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumeForDriveCubicMtr];

double VolumeForDriveLitres = [volumePerMeterLitreAnswer.text doubleValue] * [textField4.text doubleValue];
volumeForDriveLitreAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumeForDriveLitres];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an `NSNumberFormatter` with a `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle`.

For example:

```
NSNumber *sampleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1234567.8369];
NSString *numberStr = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:sampleNumber numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

`numberStr` would be: 1,234,567.837

Comment: Thank you, would I continue using @"%g" with this? And would it keep the complete numbers intact under the hood for my further calculations (please see my post above)?

Comment: It's just a formatter so your underlying numerical values are unaffected. You don't use @"%g" with this formatter.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need, I am very new, would you mind giving an exact example using this code?    [CODE]...double VolumePerMtrLitres = [volumePerMeterCubicMeterAnswer.text doubleValue] * 1000;
    volumePerMeterLitreAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", VolumePerMtrLitres];...[/CODE]     thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try %.3f where 3 is the number of decimal places instead of %g

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems to be working better but I'm not sure if it's rounding off correctly, need to experiment more. Would you also know how I can add a comma after the thousand place, so 32444.00 becomes 32,444.00?

Answer (score 0):

I know why I'm getting inaccuracy now, it's because my formulas are using the answers of my other formulas to make their calculations, and if they have already been rounded off then I get inaccuracies with the next formula!
Not sure how to get around this. I really need to keep all the figures after the decimal point and only hide the extra ones from displaying so they are still included in the calculations.
In java I would use "split" to do this but have no idea how to do in in Objective-C.